# HTML dynamic table row is not getting dynamic id

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a dynamic HTML table that makes a new row when there is a new user being registered. Now i am trying to give the row a id with a for loop but they al get the same id which is: tableID99. Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        row.id = "tableID" + i
      }
```

It looks like the table does not know it is dynamic or something. When i console.log(row.id) it is an ascending list with tableID1 -> tableID1 -> tableID2 etc.
What am i missing here?

Edit:

```
function showTable() {
  // dummy data to start with
  let localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"))

 
  // get button and table with query selector
  let createTable = document.querySelector("#table")

  // table heading
  let headers = ["ID", "Gebruikersnaam", "Email", "Wachtwoord", "Gebruikersrol", "Voornaam", "Achternaam", "Geboortedatum", "Adres", "Huisnummer", "Postcode", "Plaatsnaam", "Land", "Suspended"]


  // create table elements   
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  
  // start loop 
  headers.forEach(headerText => {
    // create table heading and textnode    
    let header = document.createElement("th");
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(headerText);
    // append to DOM   
    header.appendChild(textNode);
    headerRow.appendChild(header);
    table.appendChild(headerRow)
  });


  // create loop that makes table
  localStorageData.forEach(localStorageData => {
    blokkeerButtons()
    // create table row    
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    // create loop that set data in cells

    Object.values(localStorageData).forEach(localStorageData => {

      // create element and textnode      
      let cell = document.createElement("td");
      let textNode = document.createTextNode(localStorageData as string);

      // append to DOM   
      cell.appendChild(textNode);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        row.id = "tableID" + i
        console.log(row.id)
    
      }
    });

    // append to DOM   
    table.appendChild(row);

  });
  // append to DOM   
  createTable.appendChild(table);

}
```

Comment: `row` is not getting updated. Why assign rows with sequential ids? It's easy enough to get any row by it's HTML Collection index. Why not use the userID as a row id?

Comment: It seems like you're working with the same `row`. You need to get a reference to the new row every time.

Comment: @Kinglish userID is in local storage and i can't get it out. I've tried very long so i figured this out.

Comment: @SergeiMinaev how do i get that reference to a new row instead of it being the same row?

Comment: Consider showing the rest of the (relevant) code to get better assistance

Comment: @Kinglish i've edited the post. Might be one or 2 bugs in code but it works (i'm really new to coding)

Comment: There's alot in there that will cause errors. Rather than comment on them all, can you show what the localStorage object looks like once it's parsed?

Comment: @Kinglish see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 3 loops in your code to create the table: localStorateData.foreach, Object.values(localStorageData).forEach, and that for loop that counts from 0 to 99.

You are making exactly one new row in the outermost loop. In that innermost for loop, all you're doing is resetting the id of that one new row 100 times.

Consider changing to something like this:

```
// create loop that makes table
var rowCount = 0;
localStorageData.forEach(localStorageData => {
  blokkeerButtons()
  // create table row    
  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  // create loop that set data in cells

  Object.values(localStorageData).forEach(localStorageData => {

    // create element and textnode      
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(localStorageData as string);

    // append to DOM   
    cell.appendChild(textNode);
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });

  // append to DOM
  row.id = "tableID" + rowCount;
  rowCount++;   
  table.appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: `localStorageData.forEach(localStorageData => {` followed by `Object.values(localStorageData).forEach(localStorageData` - i guess that is allowed but it is confusing. Also, for the row id, why not just use the `index` that `forEach` can supply automatically?